# Google WebFont not rendering in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, webfonts, google-webfonts

[I have a website](http://sergedenimes.com). It uses 2 Google webfonts for its headings and body text. These work fine on Chrome/IE/Safari (including mobile) but when I view the site on my office computer running IE9 on Win7 the Google fonts do not load and fall back to a sans-serif.

Here is what I see:

**IE9:**

[image]

**Chrome:**

[image]

I cannot figure out why IE fails to load the font as I am aware that Google font's are compatible with IE7+. I figure it might be a security setting but can't get to the bottom of it. Any ideas.

Comment: Please post the code you used to embed the font (Google offers different methods)

Comment: That site seems to render the menu fonts correctly on w7-ie9.  What got fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the issue, but try changing your request to only one link tag:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Perhaps loading two fonts in two different requests causes issues.

Comment: That seems like a good idea - I should have done that anyway to reduce http requests. Away from my work PC, only got my mac now so will have to test in the morning. But thanks

Comment: The page now has such a single `link` element. Did it solve the problem? (At least now, the problem described cannot be seen in my IE 9 on Win 7.)

Comment: Yes I have changed it to a single `link` but I can't test it until the morning - will check when I get in...

Comment: Back at work and, although it was a good suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have solved it. I think it might not be a widespread problem but might be down to the settings of IE.

Answer (score 1):

On my IE9 it looked the same as in Chrome. Press F12 and make sure you are using proper Browser and Document Mode.

Comment: Yes, `Browser mode: IE9` `Document Mode: IE9 Standards`